# Fearing recursion in upon delete rows with foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, foreign-keys

I am trying to clean up a database with a load of crap records in it,

It is of a relational structure and there are foreign keys linking everything together, I have got a delete command set up:

```
DELETE FROM Members
WHERE (CurrentClass = 339) AND (YEAR(LastSessionDate) < 2011)
```

The DB structure looks like this:

```
Members
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Id ¦ FirstName ¦ LastName ¦ JoiningClass ¦ CurrentClass ¦ CurrentScheme
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
0  ¦ Fakey     ¦ McFake   ¦ 123          ¦ 999          ¦ 2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1  ¦ Fakette   ¦ McFake   ¦ 123          ¦ 998          ¦ 1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The above table references tables `Classes` and `Pricing` on the fields `JoiningClass, CurrentClass and CurrentScheme` those tables then reference other tables with fields they hold, so basically everything references everything.

I want to delete the above records that match criteria of mine but I get a foreign key warning.

I had considered adding:

```
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

To it but I am afraid as everything references everything else it will delete ALL of the database data.

I.E. If I delete record 0 above that it will delete the classes `123` and `999` and that will in turn delete all of its references.

Does this happen or should I know better?

Comment: What is the foreign key warning that you are getting?

Comment: When attempting to create the constraint you may possibly get the error described in [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321843).

Comment: @taylonr - `The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_MissedSessions_Members". The conflict occurred in the database "CENSORED", table "dbo.MissedSessions", column "Member". The statement has been terminated.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "everything references everything" as you say, then it's hard to tell what would happen exactly without some serious (read: time consuming, annoying) analysis of the schema. The same goes for using 3rd party tools - you're never 100% sure what they'll do exactly, and deleting records isn't something you want to risk on a production database.

Instead, you should create another copy of your database (backup your schema, then recreate it from backup on another server), add your cascading triggers and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that JoiningClass and CurrentClass are parents of the Members record. Therefore they won't get deleted. Certainly the message you are getting indicates that it is a different table that has child records which is causing the delete to fail. Now only you can know if that is the correct behavior, i.e. if there are child records you do not want the records to be deleted or if you want to control all deleting through cascade delete. Personally I never use cascade delete becasue it can cause performance issues if they are many child records (in which case it is best to delete them in batches first then the parent table) or you have the case above where you do not under any circumstances want to delete if the child exists. For instance you would not want to delete a customer if they have a past order that you need to have correct financial reporting, in this case you make the customer inactive rather than deleting.

Make sure you have current backups before trying any deleting with cascade delete.